# how to install a hook without a loop

Tags: c++, dll, hook

I wrote this Dynamic library to install a hook, but for the hook to function properly the program requires it to be in a while loop. Is there a way I could install the hook without using a while loop and be able to uninstall it similarly to my method called "unlock" shown below? The library is gonna be used in a C# program later on and its purpose is to block any letters coming from the keyboard and only let numbers come through. Thanks

```
#pragma once
#include "Header.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <ShlObj.h>


#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x050
HHOOK hhkLowLevelKybd = NULL;

LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    BOOL duckx = FALSE;
    BOOL ducky = FALSE;

    if (nCode == HC_ACTION)
    {
        switch (wParam)
        {
        case WM_KEYDOWN:
        case WM_SYSKEYDOWN:
        case WM_KEYUP:
        case WM_SYSKEYUP:
            PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT p = (PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT)lParam;
            if ((duckx = (p->vkCode >= 0x3a)) || (duckx = (p->vkCode <= 0x28 && p->vkCode > 0x08))) {

                break;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return(duckx ? 1 : CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam));
}

void lock() {

    HHOOK hhkLowLevelKybd = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, LowLevelKeyboardProc, 0, 0);

}
void unlock() {

    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hhkLowLevelKybd);

}
myClass::myClass(int x) {
    if (x == 1) {

        lock();
        MSG msg;
        while (!GetMessage(&msg, NULL, NULL, NULL)) {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);

            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }
    if (x == 0) {

        unlock();
        MSG msg;
        while (!GetMessage(&msg, NULL, NULL, NULL)) {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);

            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: The message loop is a rock-hard requirement.  The OS cannot simply interrupt your thread and make the callback run, that causes horrible re-entrancy bugs.  It needs to know that the thread is in a safe place, ready to do something else.  GetMessage() signals that safe place.  Use a thread if this is inconvenient.

Answer (score 1):

Many of the hooks provided by `SetWindowsHookEx()` require the installing thread to have a message loop, as their hook callbacks get delegated back to that thread when called, and that requires synchronization, which a message loop can handle.

Read the [`SetWindowsHookEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexw) documentation, it tells you specifically which hooks require a message loop.

Hint - [`WH_KEYBOARD_LL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644985(v=vs.85).aspx) is one of them:

> **This hook is called in the context of the thread that installed it**. The call is made by sending a message to the thread that installed the hook. **Therefore, the thread that installed the hook must have a message loop**.

Since you are writing a library, you cannot guarantee that the calling app has a message loop. So, you should make your library run its own worker thread that has a message loop.  That thread can (un)install the hook and process the callbacks. Have `lock()` create that thread, and `unlock()` stop it.